# ms access-storing values (control source)

Tags: ms-access

i have a text box that calculates the total in a sub form in the page footer. i then have a text box in the form footer to show users the total of the selected project. as i have done this through the control source, i would then like to save this total so that i can view it in a different form. here is a picture of what i mean.

[image]

as you can see the text box in the subform footer is called "Totaltxt" and the text box in the form footer is gathering the data from that, but not saving it.
what would the solution be to achieve the total like i have but store the total value also.

Comment: You wouldn't. It can be calculated at any time.

Comment: this is through a query though? if im trying to open this overall total in another form/ table how would i do that?

Comment: Yes. Use a query that uses the tables as source, joins these, and performs the calculation.

Comment: i am still a little confused as to what you mean. i have a for called "add jobs" this is the form i want to show the total for that project, but the form i have worked it out on (as seen above) is the "items list" form. bot completely separate tables and forms, i want to be able to view the total of the items for the the project. if that makes sense?

Comment: If you are in doubt how to create queries and use them, you must read up on this before proceeding. Next to the tables, these are the core of any database.

Comment: I don't really understand the issue. You say you have the items total already calculated on form. If that is the case then what exactly is not working?

Comment: As Gustav states, retrieve related data via queries that join tables. If join is not practical, a domain aggregate function might serve (DSum, DAvg, DCount, etc).